# Connection String via IP Address For SQL Server

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I want to create connection string so that I can connect to SQL database remotely in my C# code using OleDb as a provider and the server IP address.

Note 1 : I'm using OleDb because I want to handle different database types. SQL         is just an example.
Note 2 : The database resides on another machine (machine on another network)

I did all the setup to connect from another machine (firewall,Enable TCP/IP..etc), and now I can connect remotely using Microsoft SQL Server Management 2014 by specifying (server name : My Computer Name-PC\Instance name) and using SQL Authentication then entering the username and password and press connect and then it goes well, I connect successfully.

BUT I TRIED A LOT OF COMBINATIONS TO BUILD THE CONNECTION STRING IN MY C# CODE AND NONE OF THEM WORKS EXCEPT THIS :

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"provider = sqloledb; data source = MyCompName-PC\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog = DataBase1 ; user id = MyUsername ; password = MyPassword ;");
```

**Otherwise if I try to use my server public IP address instead of MyCompName in Data Source it keeps giving me error : server not found or access denied.**

I search in connectionstrings.com but problem is still there.

Comment: Well if it works where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

From your post it looks like you are trying to connect to a `SQL Server` database then why are you using `OleDbConnection`? instead of using `SQL Server` connection provider.

`OleDbConnection` connection provider is used for connecting to `MS Access` database.

You should be using a `SqlConnection` class like

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source = MyCompName-PC\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog = DataBase1 ; user id = MyUsername ; password = MyPassword ;")
```

See [SQLConnection Reference](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection) for more information as commented by @AlexK.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. included that link in answer.

Comment: I'm using OleDb because I want to handle different Database types.
I'm just using SQL DB in my question as an example.

And I want to use IP addresses in data source so that I can connect to the DB when it's on another network.

Imagine the SQL DB resides on a server somewhere in US and my client want to connect to it from his PC in Europe .

What's the connection string to do such a thing ? that's the question.

Comment: No, that's not a recommended as well as best way. If you really want to handle different DB types then try using `Abstract DB factory` pattern but use the exact DB provider,

Comment: Almost every popular database engine on the market today (SQL Server, Oracle, MySql, Sqlite, PostgreSql etc...) have ADO.Net connectors. I still don't get why you'd want to use `OleDbConnection`. In addition to all that, the ADO.Net providers provide you with a [ConnectionBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class that would handle all this connection string stuff for you.